# Why does visiting a file cause my to lose me custom faces?

Tags: init-file, colors

Every time I start emacs and visit my *first* reStructuredText file, I discover that I once again have the default colors for the section headings, which are illegible to me.

If I have the customizer open in another window while I open the *first* reStructuredText file, I can see the colors revert to their defaults right before my eyes.

Then, if I open my `~/.emacs` file and re-execute this statement with `C-x C-e`, the colors right themselves:

```
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(rst-level-1-face ((t (:background "blue1"))) t)
 '(rst-level-2-face ((t (:background "blue2"))) t)
 '(rst-level-3-face ((t (:background "blue3"))) t)
 '(rst-level-4-face ((t (:background "blue4"))) t)
 '(rst-level-5-face ((t (:background "navy"))) t))
```

How would I hunt down the thing that is causing my colors to change?

Comment: Sounds like some Lisp code somewhere changes the backgrounds. Did you try grepping for `rst-level.*face`? Did you also check the faces just after you start Emacs, before visiting a reStructuredText file?

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment.  I have completely recast my question.  Where would I grep for the offending Lisp code (on Linux)?

Comment: The Lisp code distributed with Emacs is in and under directory `EMACS/share/emacs/VERSION/lisp/`, where `EMACS is the directory where you installed Emacs and `VERSION` is the Emacs release number. But you might also be loading Lisp code from other libraries. Perhaps you load a library whose name contains `rst`? If so, try grepping there. (You can also get to the distribution's `lisp/` directory by doing `M-x find-library RET subr.el` and then doing `C-x d`.)